# copy processed mp3 files from one directory to another directory in php

Tags: php

I am working on a php code as shown below which is converting **mp4 files into mp3 using ffmpeg**. After conversion, everything goes into **outgoing_folder**.

```
<?php
const DS = '/';
$src_dir    = 'incoming_folder';   /* Place where mp4 file is present */

$destination = 'outgoing_folder';  /* Place where mp3 files come after conversion from mp4 */

$mp3_processed = 'podcast_mp3_processed'; /* Place where I also want mp3 files */

foreach ($mp4_files as $f)
{

    $parts = pathinfo($f);
    switch ($parts['extension'])
    {
        case 'mp4' :
            $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
            system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);    /** Place where mp3 file goes after conversion from mp4 **/

            if ($result)
            {
                // Do something with result if you want
                // log for example
            }
            break;

        case 'mp3' :
            // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
            copy($f, $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
            copy('outgoing_folder', 'podcast_mp3_processed');   /* Line #A */
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that when all mp4 files have been converted to mp3 then it should also go to **podcast_mp3_processed** folder.

At this moment it is going outgoing_folder but I also want it to go to **podcast_mp3_processed** folder. I tried with the code at **Line#A** but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy a directory and the PHP copy function only handles files.
Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

You can change your **Line #A** by duplicating the line before it and simply changing the directory variable `$destination` with `$mp3_processed`.

```
copy($f, $mp3_processed. DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
```

Comment: like this ?       `case 'mp3' :
            // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
            copy($f, $destination . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
            copy($f, $mp3_processed. DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
            break;`